# adwords api: retrieve daily spend (costs)

Tags: python, api, google-api, google-ads-api

Does anybody have some sample code that shows how to get the daily, total spend (across all campaigns) of an AdWords account?

I haven't been able to find sample code that does something like this in a straightforward manner, so any help, pointers,code would be appreciated. (I'll use the python lib but any other language is cool, too...)

Thanks in advance!

Hoff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Python but the process should be similar in any language so this PHP might be of some help:

```
$user = new AdWordsUser();

// Get the CampaignService.
$campaignService = $user->GetCampaignService('v201101');

// Create selector.
$selector = new Selector();
// Fields to retrieve
$selector->fields = array('Id', 'Name', 'Cost');
// Date rage for stats
$selector->dateRange->min = "20110613";
$selector->dateRange->max = "20110614";

// Get all campaigns.
$page = $campaignService->get($selector);

if(isset($page->entries)){
    foreach ($page->entries as $campaign) {
        if(isset($campaign->campaignStats)) {
            // This is how you get the cost
            $cost = $campaign->campaignStats->cost->microAmount/1000000;
            print "Cost for Campaign {$campaign->name} = $cost\n";
        }
    }
}
```

You should be able to use the `get_all_campaigns.py` example [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-python-lib/source/browse/trunk/examples/adspygoogle/adwords/v201101/get_all_campaigns.py) to write the equivalent Python code.

Comment: thanks for the answer. but is there any way to get  this stats by individual date wise in single API call ? like if i provide dates 12-08-2013 to 20-08-2013. it should provide me stats of every single day not the average of all those days. any possibility ?

Comment: This code is no longer working cf http://googleadsdeveloper.blogspot.com.au/2013/10/adwords-api-how-to-migrate-from-stats.html