# Adwords API : How to get total spent amount for an ad-group

Tags: php, google-ads-api

There are examples on the internet showing how to get daily spend per campaign. e.g : [adwords api: retrieve daily spend (costs)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359972/adwords-api-retrieve-daily-spend-costs?rq=1)

But I want to get total spent amount for an ad-group, using the ad-group-id. I'm using PHP client library. Is it possible to obtain that data per ad-group? if yes, please show me an example.

Answer (score 0):

Using the example you're quoting, instead of

```
    // Date rage for stats
    $selector->dateRange->min = "20110613";
    $selector->dateRange->max = "20110614";
```

do this:

```
    // Date rage for stats
    $selector->dateRange->min = "20000101";
    $selector->dateRange->max = "20250101";
```

Basically, asking for all stats from 2000 to 2025.

Make sure to revisit in 12 years :)

Comment: Or, you know, use something like `date("Y")+2`